# Python, iterating and modifying DataFrames in a dictionary of df's

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, vectorization

Coming from a C# background (years ago) and being very new to Python I'm struggling to optimise my code. Literally just learned that for loops are very slow.

In the code below the loop that adds a calculated column to each DataFrame in the Dict appears to be a huge bottleneck.

I've read up on ways to fix this, such as; [Vectorisation](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) and [Numba](https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-your-algorithms-part-2-numba-293e554c5cc1) but don't think I know enough Python to really understand and utilise them.

In fact my attempts with both have failed, probably incorrect implementation, apart from a test I did with np.where. This showed me how bad my for loop / calc was.

I'll leave out these attempts in my working example but can add later if needs be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as date
import itertools

def points(row):
val = 0
if row['Ob2'] > 0.5:
    foo = row['Ob3'] - row['Ob1']
    if foo < 0.1:
        val = 1 - foo
else:
    val = 0
return val

print("Start: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

player_list = ['player' + str(x) for x in range(1,71)]

data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': player_list*1000,\
                   'Ob1' : np.random.rand(70000),\
                   'Ob2' : np.random.rand(70000) ,\
                   'Ob3' : np.random.rand(70000)})

#create list of unique pairs
comboNames = list(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2))

#create a data frame dictionary to store your data frames
DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in comboNames}

for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    DataFrameDict[key] = data[:][data.Names.isin(key)]
    DataFrameDict[key] = DataFrameDict[key].sort_values(['Ob1'])

print("DF fill: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

#Add test calculated column
for tbl in DataFrameDict:
    DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'] = DataFrameDict[tbl].apply(points, axis=1) #Slow loop
    #example vectorised, hugh dif is run time
    #DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'] = np.where((DataFrameDict[tbl]['Ob2']>0.5),1,0)

print("Calc'd: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

headers = ['Player1','Player2','Score','Count']
summary = pd.DataFrame(([tbl[0], tbl[1], DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].sum(),
                      DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].astype(bool).sum(axis=0)] for tbl in DataFrameDict),
                      columns=headers).sort_values(['Score'], ascending=[False])

print("Fin: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()
```

**EDIT: The function adds a column which is a comparison of the two "players" in each df so we / I can't apply it to the source df. Apologies for not being clearer.**

I obviously need to backtrack and learn some Python fundamentals but my boss is waiting on the real script, which took 3 hours to run what would be a standard 500 "Names" (125K~ dataframes).

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me optimise it!

**EDIT2**: Better representation of real world problem

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as date
import itertools

def random_dates(start, end, n, unit='D', seed=None):
    if not seed:
        np.random.seed(0)

    ndays = (end - start).days + 1
    return pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(n) * ndays, unit=unit) + start

def points(row):
    val = 0
    if row['Names'] != row['Names2']:
        secs = row['Dates'] - row['Dates2']
        secs = secs.total_seconds()
        if secs in range(1, 301):
            val = 301 - secs
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

print("Start: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

player_list = ['player' + str(x) for x in range(1,71)]

np.random.seed(0)
start = pd.to_datetime('2019-04-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2019-04-10')

data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': player_list*1000,
                     'Dates': random_dates(start, end, 70000)})

#create list of unique pairs
comboNames = list(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2))

#create a data frame dictionary to store your data frames
DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in comboNames}

for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    DataFrameDict[key] = data[:][data.Names.isin(key)]
    DataFrameDict[key] = DataFrameDict[key].sort_values(['Dates'])
    DataFrameDict[key]['Names2'] = DataFrameDict[key]['Names'].shift(1)
    DataFrameDict[key]['Dates2'] = DataFrameDict[key]['Dates'].shift(1)

print("DF fill: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

#Add test calculated column
for tbl in DataFrameDict:
    DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'] = DataFrameDict[tbl].apply(points, axis=1) #Slow loop
    #example vectorised, hugh dif is run time
    #DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'] = np.where((DataFrameDict[tbl]['Ob2']>0.5),1,0)

print("Calc'd: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

headers = ['Player1','Player2','Score','Count']
summary = pd.DataFrame(([tbl[0], tbl[1], DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].sum(),
                      DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].astype(bool).sum(axis=0)] for tbl in DataFrameDict),
                      columns=headers).sort_values(['Score'], ascending=[False])

print("Fin: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()
```

My **[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55671862/5608428)**, didn't want to post here due to clutter.

Comment: what is player_list

Comment: Sorry, missed that line when posting. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Is there a reason your doing ```for tbl in DataFrameDict:
    DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'] = DataFrameDict[tbl].apply(points, axis=1)``` after creating the dict? Your function doesnt care whether its for the dict key (player1, player3) or (player1, player2) because the player1 rows aren't effected by the other players. In otherwords, you would save a ton of time doing the apply on the original df and not each dict key.

Comment: Hi @Ben, yes there is a reason that probably isn't apparent in the working example above. Basically the function adds a column which is a comparison of the two "players" in each df so we / I can't apply it to the source df. Apologies for not being clearer and thanks for the input below.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as date
import itertools

player_list = ['player' + str(x) for x in range(1,71)]

data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': player_list*1000,\
                   'Ob1' : np.random.rand(70000),\
                   'Ob2' : np.random.rand(70000) ,\
                   'Ob3' : np.random.rand(70000)})

data['Test'] = np.where(data['Ob2'] > 0.5, np.where(data['Ob3'] - data['Ob1'] < 0.1, 1 - (data['Ob3'] - data['Ob1']), 0), 0)


comboNames = list(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2))
DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in comboNames}

for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    DataFrameDict[key] = data[:][data.Names.isin(key)]
    DataFrameDict[key] = DataFrameDict[key].sort_values(['Ob1'])

headers = ['Player1','Player2','Score','Count']
summary = pd.DataFrame(([tbl[0], tbl[1], DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].sum(),
                      DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].astype(bool).sum(axis=0)] for tbl in DataFrameDict),
                      columns=headers).sort_values(['Score'], ascending=[False])
```

I tried to keep as much as your code as possible. I changed your function to use np.where instead of apply, and added the test column before creating the dict, because as I expressed in my comment, there's no point in doing the apply at that point.

With `%%timeit` I got 26.2 s ± 1.15 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

**EDIT:**

This is as fast as I could make it:

```
%%timeit

player_list = ['player' + str(x) for x in range(1,71)]

data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': player_list*1000,\
                    'Ob1' : np.random.rand(70000),\
                    'Ob2' : np.random.rand(70000) ,\
                    'Ob3' : np.random.rand(70000)})

# Calculating the individual total test score for each row in data
data['test'] = np.where(data['Ob2'] > 0.5, np.where(data['Ob3'] - data['Ob1'] < 0.1, 1 - (data['Ob3'] - data['Ob1']), 0), 0)

# The goal of this function is to get the sum, and count of the test score for each player
def ScoreAndCount(row):
    score = row.sum()
    count = row.astype(bool).sum()
    return score, count

# Applying the function above, I group by each player and 
# get the total sum of test and the total count for each player.
df = data.groupby('Names')['test'].apply(ScoreAndCount).reset_index()
df = pd.concat([df['Names'], df.test.apply(pd.Series).rename(columns = {0: 'Score', 1:'Count'})], axis = 1)

# Using itertools I create a dataframe Summary that has two columns covering
# every single matchup between player, and label the columns Player1 and Player2
summary = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2), columns = ['Player1', 'Player2'])

# Below ,I merge summary with my dataframe that contains the total score and count 
# for each player. Every single time there is a player1 in the Player1 column it
# will merge the their total score and count, the same is then done for the 
# players in the Player2 column. After these merges I have 6 columns. The two 
# player columns, and the total scores and counts for both individuals.
summary = summary.merge(df, left_on = 'Player1', right_on = 'Names')\
                 .merge(df, left_on = 'Player2', right_on = 'Names')\
                 .drop(columns = ['Names_x', 'Names_y'])

# Below, I add the players 'Score' and 'Count' columns to get the total score
# and total count per iteration. Then I clean the df dropping the columns that 
# are not needed, and sorting by score.
summary['Score'] = summary['Score_x'] + summary['Score_y']
summary['Count'] = summary['Count_x'] + summary['Count_y']
summary.drop(columns = ['Score_x','Count_x', 'Score_y','Count_y'], inplace = True)
summary.sort_values('Score', ascending = False)

157 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

My goal was to not use loops or dicts to increase the speed further.

My function ScoreAndCount returns what would be the score and count for every single player. The pd.concat takes the return of that function and adds it to our initial df.

I then took the ittertools combo and made it its own dataframe called summary. I then merged on both the player1 and player2 columns of the summary df with the names column in the original df.

Next, I added up the scores and counts for the players, dropped the unnecessary columns, and sorted. I ended up with 157ms per loop. The slowest steps would be the concat and the merge, but I couldn't figure out a way to get around them and further increase speed.

**EDIT3**

We're going to set a seed and use the same data df for both tests:

```
np.random.seed(0)

player_list = ['player' + str(x) for x in range(1,71)]

data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': player_list*10,\
                    'Ob1' : np.random.rand(700),\
                    'Ob2' : np.random.rand(700) ,\
                    'Ob3' : np.random.rand(700)})

data.head()

      Names    Ob1         Ob2         Ob3
0   player1 0.548814    0.373216    0.313591
1   player2 0.715189    0.222864    0.365539
2   player3 0.602763    0.080532    0.201267
3   player4 0.544883    0.085311    0.487148
4   player5 0.423655    0.221396    0.990369
```

Next we will use your exact code, and inspect the dict between player1 and player2.

```
def points(row):
    val = 0
    if row['Ob2'] > 0.5:
        foo = row['Ob3'] - row['Ob1']
        if foo < 0.1:
            val = 1 - foo
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

#create list of unique pairs
comboNames = list(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2))
DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in comboNames}

for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    DataFrameDict[key] = data[:][data.Names.isin(key)]
    DataFrameDict[key] = DataFrameDict[key].sort_values(['Ob1'])

#Add test calculated column
for tbl in DataFrameDict:
    DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'] = DataFrameDict[tbl].apply(points, axis=1)

DataFrameDict[('player1', 'player2')].head()

     Names     Ob1        Ob2          Ob3     Test
351 player2 0.035362    0.013509    0.384273    0.0
630 player1 0.062636    0.305047    0.571550    0.0
561 player2 0.133461    0.758194    0.964210    0.0
211 player2 0.216897    0.056877    0.417333    0.0
631 player2 0.241902    0.557987    0.983555    0.0
```

Next we will do what you do in the summary and take the sum of the test column, this will be the score generated for player1 and player2

```
DataFrameDict[('player1', 'player2')]['Test'].sum()

8.077455441105938
```

So we end up with 8.0774. Now if what I'm saying is true, if we do my code in Edit2 we will end up with 8.077 for the score between player1 and player2.

```
data['test'] = np.where(data['Ob2'] > 0.5, np.where(data['Ob3'] - data['Ob1'] < 0.1, 1 - (data['Ob3'] - data['Ob1']), 0), 0)

def ScoreAndCount(row):
    score = row.sum()
    count = row.astype(bool).sum()
    return score, count

df = data.groupby('Names')['test'].apply(ScoreAndCount).reset_index()
df = pd.concat([df['Names'], df.test.apply(pd.Series).rename(columns = {0: 'Score', 1:'Count'})], axis = 1)

summary = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2), columns = ['Player1', 'Player2'])
summary = summary.merge(df, left_on = 'Player1', right_on = 'Names')\
                 .merge(df, left_on = 'Player2', right_on = 'Names')\
                 .drop(columns = ['Names_x', 'Names_y'])

summary['Score'] = summary['Score_x'] + summary['Score_y']
summary['Count'] = summary['Count_x'] + summary['Count_y']
summary.drop(columns = ['Score_x','Count_x', 'Score_y','Count_y'], inplace = True)
summary = summary.sort_values('Score', ascending = False)
```

Now we will inspect the row with player1 and player2

```
summary[(summary['Player1'] == 'player1')&(summary['Player2'] == 'player2')]

    Player1 Player2   Score    Count
0   player1 player2 8.077455    6.0
```

As you can see, I calculated the exact same score from player1 player2 through my edit2 as you did in your code.

Comment: your edit is interesting. I do remember thinking the must be a way to bypass the Dict of DataFrames and pull just the results (aggregations) from the source df. Given my requirement to calculated the "Score" of each combo (each sub df as is) do you think this could be achieved? I.e. Test column not applied to "data" but somewhere within your merge for playerX vs. playerY

Comment: So in your original code, you calculate the sum of the test column for both players. For example, in the player1 vs player2 and the player1 vs player3, the first row of each would be the exact same player 1 row. What I did in my edit is I took the sum of the individuals before iterating as it makes no difference. After iterating I add the sum of the individual test together to get the total sum. This can be seen in the ```summary['Score'] = summary['Score_x'] + summary['Score_y'] ```. Score_x and Score_y are the individual total test, which when summed give you the score you want.

Comment: Please see my Edit to the question or my comment on the main in reply to you. Each dataframe is a comparison of a pair . So just to clarify , the test column must be added to each df as it in reality is a comparrison between playX and playerY attributes. In my example code I made a function that operates similarly but not exactly the same meaning the distinction is not very apparent which is my fault, so apologies.

Comment: But the goal of your code is the summary df is it not? The dicts are just an intermediate. If the dicts between players are your goal then thats a different question, however, I was working on the assumption that the summary df is your goal, thus my 2nd edit code should give you the exact same answer as your original code with a different approach.

Comment: The end goal is the summary yes, but the 'test' column cannot be applied to the data df, it must be applied to each player v player sub df. I wouldn't have bothered creating the dictionary of df's if I could just compute scores using the source df ('data')

Comment: However, that is 100% not true. Let me make an edit 3 to show you that my summary score in edit2 for player1 and player2 is the exact same as looking at the player1 and player2 dict, applying your function, then doing the sum on the test column created by your function.

Comment: Yes, because in my demo code the score is a simple calculation based on each players row. So of course player1's score will be the same in every combo of player1 vs. playerX. My real world problem is a comparison, i.e the func is comparing attributes from player1 to playerX. This means we can't simply compute the score on data as this has all players in it.. we need to create separate df's for each pairing in order for it to work. I apologised for not being clearer about this but I also did ask how to optimise the loop at the same time.

Comment: Ohhhh, so your actually using a different function? My whole point was optimizing around the function you gave so you didn't have to use a dict. If that's not the actual function your using then I can't optimize around a dict. Given the correct function or something more similar, I may be able to though.

Comment: Yeah, it all boils down to my newness to Python in general. Didn't see the difference until you and others posted. As said before, my bad. I've made some progress myself but will add an edit with a better representation of the function.

Comment: Agreed @Cr1064, while it operates on data rather than it's sub (player v player) df's I still learned a lot from it. Thanks Ben

Answer (score 1):

I was able to vectorize your function with numba and the resulting code runs in ~8 seconds with %%timeit. I followed the advice of Ben Pap and calculated the test column beforehand. I also sorted the values beforehand and tidied up the DataFrameDict creation.

```py
%%timeit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as date
import itertools
import numba

@numba.vectorize
def points(a,b,c):
    val = 0
    if b > 0.5:
        foo = c - a
        if foo < 0.1:
            val = 1 - foo
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

player_list = ['player' + str(x) for x in range(1,71)]

data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': player_list*1000,\
                   'Ob1' : np.random.rand(70000),\
                   'Ob2' : np.random.rand(70000) ,\
                   'Ob3' : np.random.rand(70000)})

data['Test'] = points(data['Ob1'].values,data['Ob2'].values,data['Ob3'].values)
data = data.sort_values(['Ob1'])

comboNames = list(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2))
DataFrameDict = {elem : data.loc[data.Names.isin(elem)] for elem in comboNames}

headers = ['Player1','Player2','Score','Count']
summary = pd.DataFrame(([tbl[0], tbl[1], DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].sum(),
                      DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].astype(bool).sum(axis=0)] for tbl in DataFrameDict),
                      columns=headers).sort_values(['Score'], ascending=[False])
```

8.52 s ± 204 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: My attempt to optimise the function was very similar except I imported `jit` from `numba` and used `@jit`, also forgot the `.values` in  `DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'] = points(DataFrameDict[tbl]['Ob1'].values,\..`. Your way while keeping the for loop, as per my comment to Ben, has reduced the run time to 29s which is a big improvement!

Answer (score 1):

I focus on your function `point` and the for loop where `apply` got called.

The function `Point` can translate into this condition(`a_df` is each DataFrame in `DataFrameDict`):

```
(a_df['Ob2'] > 0.5) & (a_df['Ob3'] - a_df['Ob1'] < 0.01)
```

On this condition assign values `1 - x['Ob3'] + x['Ob1']` to `Test` column. Everything else assigns 0 to `Test`. So, let's assign new column `Test` to each `a_df`. Then, filter only rows qualify for the condition above to narrow down data set and set new values to this subset. Finally, update this subset `Test` column value back to a_df['Test'] and assign it back to `DataFrameDict` dictionary. So, your for loop would turned to be:

```
for tbl in DataFrameDict:        
    a_df = DataFrameDict[tbl].assign(Test=0)
    a_df['Test'].update(a_df[(a_df['Ob2'] > 0.5) & (a_df['Ob3'] - a_df['Ob1'] < 0.01)].assign(Test=lambda x: 1 - x['Ob3'] + x['Ob1'])['Test'])
    DataFrameDict[tbl] = a_df
```

This ran quite fast

*Output*: Every DataFrame of `DataFrameDict` got populated `Test` columns according to specified condition. I pick a random final DataFrame from `DataFrameDict` to show the output.

```
In [1288]: DataFrameDict[('player65', 'player67')]
Out[1288]:
          Names       Ob1       Ob2       Ob3      Test
61456  player67  0.000271  0.686051  0.729086  0.000000
25824  player65  0.001281  0.505552  0.296550  0.000000
25544  player65  0.001398  0.770805  0.471477  0.000000
65864  player65  0.001999  0.147407  0.291841  0.000000
33104  player65  0.002661  0.254329  0.126290  0.000000
42554  player65  0.003172  0.529603  0.181796  0.000000
28064  player65  0.003663  0.227429  0.558233  0.000000
24844  player65  0.005517  0.096817  0.710771  0.000000
2584   player65  0.005974  0.338904  0.582034  0.000000
42694  player65  0.005996  0.171637  0.765277  0.000000
6154   player65  0.006126  0.181239  0.295149  0.000000
65234  player65  0.008386  0.180613  0.994273  0.000000
5034   player65  0.008921  0.013060  0.305063  0.000000
21766  player67  0.010950  0.590966  0.481547  0.000000
53054  player65  0.010957  0.731794  0.262754  0.000000
15956  player67  0.010996  0.046718  0.153172  0.000000
36046  player67  0.011634  0.250039  0.064184  0.000000
50394  player65  0.011835  0.995986  0.834281  0.000000
64326  player67  0.011974  0.499262  0.745194  0.000000
30236  player67  0.013029  0.101714  0.143509  0.000000
23374  player65  0.014865  0.158185  0.575582  0.000000
1256   player67  0.014915  0.938301  0.629850  0.000000
10216  player67  0.015122  0.450750  0.137085  0.000000
21904  player65  0.016372  0.147897  0.786882  0.000000
34854  player65  0.016603  0.513692  0.676243  0.000000
33806  player67  0.016820  0.063896  0.577731  0.000000
29816  player67  0.017565  0.060496  0.151780  0.000000
6924   player65  0.017652  0.121581  0.117512  0.000000
39126  player67  0.017990  0.516819  0.663672  0.000000
39896  player67  0.018085  0.031526  0.075832  0.000000
...         ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
61526  player67  0.985386  0.512073  0.754241  1.231145
48926  player67  0.985504  0.007080  0.671456  0.000000
16234  player65  0.985775  0.846647  0.998181  0.000000
12736  player67  0.985846  0.283997  0.667314  0.000000
47874  player65  0.986084  0.052026  0.508918  0.000000
29886  player67  0.986655  0.998440  0.068136  1.918518
49416  player67  0.986706  0.833053  0.182814  1.803892
42486  player67  0.986797  0.608128  0.136219  1.850578
55644  player65  0.987796  0.215898  0.561002  0.000000
1814   player65  0.987935  0.324954  0.525433  0.000000
7554   player65  0.988910  0.664914  0.674546  1.314365
59774  player65  0.989147  0.235214  0.913588  0.000000
58444  player65  0.989467  0.645191  0.533468  1.455999
62856  player67  0.989470  0.523544  0.302838  1.686632
48646  player67  0.990588  0.522521  0.201132  1.789456
11336  player67  0.990629  0.932360  0.756544  1.234085
31774  player65  0.990881  0.981641  0.943824  1.047057
18964  player65  0.992287  0.808989  0.948321  1.043967
14486  player67  0.992909  0.437701  0.484678  0.000000
12246  player67  0.994027  0.542903  0.234830  1.759197
33596  player67  0.994257  0.949055  0.098368  1.895889
6436   player67  0.994661  0.444211  0.572136  0.000000
4194   player65  0.995022  0.721113  0.584195  1.410826
42696  player67  0.995065  0.516103  0.918737  1.076328
51026  player67  0.995864  0.877335  0.516737  1.479127
14136  player67  0.997691  0.134021  0.913969  0.000000
47664  player65  0.998051  0.628051  0.722695  1.275357
55924  player65  0.998079  0.828749  0.151217  1.846863
18474  player65  0.998780  0.200990  0.098713  0.000000
41296  player67  0.998884  0.167139  0.504899  0.000000

[2000 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I like it, _to me_ it's tidier looking than using the func and I learned a little about working with df's. Pity it's 2x slower than @Cr1064 's vectorisation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is the indentation of lines 6 to 14 not shrinking?

```py
def points(row):
    val = 0
    if row['Ob2'] > 0.5:
        foo = row['Ob3'] - row['Ob1']
        if foo < 0.1:
            val = 1 - foo
    else:
        val = 0
    return val
```

Comment: Please note, that all posts to Stack Overflow are required to be in English. Update your answer using the *edit* button and take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/) for details.

Comment: That was down to me not ctrl+K'ing properly to indent the code properly here, in the actual code it's indented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Partly influence by @andy 's answer, thanks. Greatly reduces runtime compared to my Edit2 code.

Removed the func and did all calcs with np.where:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as date
import itertools

def random_dates(start, end, n, unit='D', seed=None):
    if not seed:
        np.random.seed(0)

    ndays = (end - start).days + 1
    return pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(n) * ndays, unit=unit) + start

print("Start: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

player_list = ['player' + str(x) for x in range(1,71)]

np.random.seed(0)
start = pd.to_datetime('2019-04-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2019-04-10')

data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': player_list*1000,
                     'Dates': random_dates(start, end, 70000)})

#create list of unique pairs
comboNames = list(itertools.combinations(data.Names.unique(), 2))

#create a data frame dictionary to store your data frames
DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in comboNames}

for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    DataFrameDict[key] = data[:][data.Names.isin(key)]
    DataFrameDict[key] = DataFrameDict[key].sort_values(['Dates'])
    seconds = (DataFrameDict[key]['Dates'] - DataFrameDict[key]['Dates'].shift(1))/ np.timedelta64(1,'s')
    DataFrameDict[key]['Test'] = np.where((DataFrameDict[key]['Names'] != DataFrameDict[key]['Names'].shift(1))&\
                                              (np.logical_and(seconds>=1, seconds<=301)), 301-seconds,0).astype(np.uint8)

print("DF fill: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()

headers = ['Player1','Player2','Score','Count']
summary = pd.DataFrame(([tbl[0], tbl[1], DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].sum(),
                      DataFrameDict[tbl]['Test'].astype(bool).sum(axis=0)] for tbl in DataFrameDict),
                      columns=headers).sort_values(['Score'], ascending=[False])

print("Fin: "+ str(date.datetime.now()))
print()
```